# The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation

Tags: vb.net, ftpwebrequest

First off all sorry for the trivial question I am a newbie and still learning. I am using vb.net to build an application that connect into a FTP Server list the files and filter this files according with the file extension. Then download and delete the file.

I am getting the error: "The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation"

Here is where I call the methods.

```
Call GetDirectoryListing(strExtension, strPastaDownload, strUser, strPsswd)
        strFileNumber = Cont_Files
        Dim blnDownloaded As Boolean = False
        If Cont_Files > 0 Then
            For cont = 0 To Cont_Files - 1
                nameFile = arrArq(cont)
                strFilename = UCase(nameFile)
                strLocal = AppPath & strLocalArquivos & "\" & nameFile
                blnDownloaded = mFTP.FtpDownloadFile(strPastaDownload, strNomedoArquivo, strLocal, strUsuario, strSenha)
                StrDir = Dir(strdirectory)
                strRemote = nameFile
                If StrDir <> "" Then
                    FileCopy(AppPath & strfiledirectory & "\" & Trim(strRemote), strLocalBackup & "\" & Trim(strRemote))
                    mFTP.FtpDeleteFile(strServer, strPastaFtp, strFilename, strUsuario, strSenha)
                End If
            Next
```

Here is the function to list the files I am not getting any errors here just to illustrate

```
  Public Function GetDirectoryListing(ByVal sFilter As String, ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strLogin As String, ByVal strPassword As String) As ArrayList

    Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = Nothing
    Try
        ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(strServer))
        With ftpRequest
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(strLogin, strPassword)
            .UsePassive = True
            .Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
            .KeepAlive = True
        End With
        'ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory  'List, not Download
        'Read the contents of the directory and store it into a string array
        Dim srReader As New StreamReader(ftpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        sDirectoryList = srReader.ReadToEnd().Split(vbNewLine)
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(sDirectoryList) - 1
            If sFilter = Mid(sDirectoryList(i), Len(sDirectoryList(i)) - 2, 3) Then
                listaArquivo.Add(sDirectoryList(i))
            End If

        Next

        'Clear the last split vbNewLine
        If sDirectoryList IsNot Nothing Then
            sDirectoryList(sDirectoryList.Length - 1) = ""
        End If

        srReader.Close()
        srReader = Nothing
        GetDirectoryListing = listaArquivo
        ftpRequest = Nothing


    Catch ex As WebException
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to get directory listing. GetDirectoryListing()")
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is the function to download

```
Public Function FtpDownloadFile(ByVal strUrl As String, ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal strTargetDirectory As String, ByVal strLogin As String, ByVal strPassword As String) As Boolean

        Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = Nothing
        Dim ftpResponse As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim strFtpFile As String = ""
        Dim strTargetFile As String = ""
        Dim strmReader As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim strmResponse As Stream = Nothing
        Dim strmTarget As Stream = Nothing
        Dim strmWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing

        strFtpFile = strUrl & "/" & Trim(strFileName)
        strTargetFile = strTargetDirectory

        Try
            ftpRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strFtpFile), FtpWebRequest)

            With ftpRequest
                .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(strLogin, strPassword)
                .UsePassive = True
                .Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                .KeepAlive = True
            End With

            ftpResponse = CType(ftpRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse) 'line where I am getting the error

            strmTarget = New FileStream(strTargetFile, FileMode.Create)
            strmWriter = New StreamWriter(strmTarget)
            strmResponse = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream()
            strmReader = New StreamReader(strmResponse, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            strmWriter.Write(strmReader.ReadToEnd())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex

        Finally
        If strmReader IsNot Nothing Then
            strmReader.Close()
            strmReader.Dispose()
        End If

        If strmWriter IsNot Nothing Then
            strmWriter.Close()
            strmWriter.Dispose()
        End If

        If ftpResponse IsNot Nothing Then
            ftpResponse.Close()
            ftpResponse = Nothing
        End If


        If ftpRequest IsNot Nothing Then ftpRequest = Nothing
    End Try


    Return True

End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the issue is in your `FtpDownloadFile` method on the line that converts the `WebRequest` into a `FtpWebRequest`.  They are not the same.

```
ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(strServer))
ftpRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strFtpFile), FtpWebRequest)
```

Try making sure you connect to the server the same way every time. Use the way that works.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you for your help. I changed as you suggest, but now I am getting another error The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access). I checked and the files exist in the folder. Any thoughts?